# Firebase event parameters not being logged with method #1, but works with method #2. Why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Currently, I initialize Firebase Analytics in my application class like this:

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    }

    public static FirebaseAnalytics getFirebaseAnalytics() {
        return mFirebaseAnalytics;
    }

}
```

I have a handler class, `FirebaseHandler`, which handles all logging:

```
public class FirebaseHandler {

    /**
     * Log an event to Firebase, without a bundle.
     */
    public static void logEvent(String event) {
        App.getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(event, null);
    }

    /**
     * Log an event to Firebase, with a bundle
     */
    public static void logEvent(String event, Bundle bundle) {

        // I've removed some other code which makes checks on the bundle here

        App.getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(event, bundle);
    }

}
```

Then, when I want to log an event inside an activity, I do the following:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE, "TestSource");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.MEDIUM, "TestMedium");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CAMPAIGN, "TestCampaign");

FirebaseHandler.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.CAMPAIGN_DETAILS, bundle);
FirebaseHandler.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, bundle);
```

However, I noticed that this isn't actually logging the event's parameters in Google Analytics, but when I change the last two lines to the following, it works:

```
App.getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.CAMPAIGN_DETAILS, bundle);
App.getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, bundle);
```

Why is this? What's going on here that is stopping the parameters from being logged in the first block of code, but not the second?